# Filtering on the positive values in scatterplot

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, filter

Imagine a nested dictionary, where the first level is the dates, and the second level dictionary has the number as keys and the value corresponding to that number as values. I want to do a scatterplot on the positive **values** of each date without losing the dates as the x-axis. What I mean is that if the nested dictionary (one specific date), has no positive values (all zero or negative), I don't want to lose the date, but have nothing showing up as the y-axis value for the date.

Here's a working example for clarification. I plot everything in here. I want to keep the same labels and distance on x-axis but don't have the zero or negative values in y-axis show up. In this example, I don't want to see the dots on dates '2006-02-03' and '2006-04-05'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictt = {('2005-01-04', '2006-01-04'): {0: 0, 1: 3, 2: -1, 3: 5}, ('2005-02-03', '2006-02-03'): {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0},
('2005-03-07', '2006-03-07'):  {0: -3, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 5}, ('2005-04-06', '2006-04-05'):  {0: -2, 1: -3, 2: -1, 3: -2}}

for k in list(dictt.keys()):
    for i in range(4):
        plt.scatter(k[1], dictt[k[0], k[1]][i])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you prefer for the bottom line? Zero (my preference) or the minimum value of the plotted values? I've provided both solutions!

Moreover, I provided a solution that labels the points according to the value of the *n* parameter. I think of this as an improvement, what do you think?

[image]

And here it is the code, it's a bit complicated because, because, oh well, your data format IS complicated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictt = {('2005-01-04', '2006-01-04'): {0:  0, 1:  3, 2: -1, 3:  5},
         ('2005-02-03', '2006-02-03'): {0:  0, 1:  0, 2:  0, 3:  0},
         ('2005-03-07', '2006-03-07'): {0: -3, 1:  0, 2:  3, 3:  5}, 
         ('2005-04-06', '2006-04-05'): {0: -2, 1: -3, 2: -1, 3: -2}}

dates = [k[1] for k in dictt.keys()]

by_n = {} # reorder data according to the second layer of ordinality
for (d0, d1), d in dictt.items():
        for n in d.keys():
            if n not in by_n: by_n[n] = [] # empty list
            by_n[n].append((d1, d[n] if d[n]>0 else None))

fig, (ax0, axmin) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8,3), layout='constrained')

# first, using 0 as the bottom line    
for n, by_date in by_n.items(): ax0.scatter(*zip(*by_date), label='n=%d'%n)
for day in dates: ax0.scatter(day, 0, s=0)
ax0.legend()

# next, using the minimum value, that of course we must compute 
min_val = min([n for d in dictt.values() for n in d.values if n>0])
for n, by_date in by_n.items(): axmin.scatter(*zip(*by_date), label='n=%d'%n)
for day in dates: axmin.scatter(day, min_val, s=0)
axmin.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there anyway to get distinct colors for each ```n```, if it is bigger than 10?

Comment: @statwoman With us speaking of Matplotlib, not only it's possible, but you have different options. my suggestion is to use a colormap, e.g., `cm = plt.get_cmap('Spectral')` and later `for n, by_date in by_n.items(): ax0.scatter(*zip(*by_date), label='n=%d'%n, color=cm(n/(N-1))` where `N` is the total number of `n`'s. Let me know if you have problems implementing the colormap solution, ciao

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by using `ylim()` and then scattering the 0s with white dots. here's the doc link for `ylim()`:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim

The code would look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict = {
    ("2005-01-04", "2006-01-04"): {0: 0, 1: 3, 2: -1, 3: 5},
    ("2005-02-03", "2006-02-03"): {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0},
    ("2005-03-07", "2006-03-07"): {0: -3, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 5},
    ("2005-04-06", "2006-04-05"): {0: -2, 1: -3, 2: -1, 3: -2},
}


values = [list(item.values()) for item in list(dict.values())] # this line and the next line would get all the y values from dictionary and then find the maximum to set the top limit for y-axis, you should actually set the top as well as bottom so your plot looks like before
flat_list = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist] # flattens the y values
plt.ylim(bottom=0, top=max(flat_list) + 0.5)
for k in list(dict.keys()):
    for i in range(4):
        if dict[k[0], k[1]][i] == 0: # if you wanna have the 0 values remove this if
            plt.scatter(k[1], dict[k[0], k[1]][i], color="white")
        else:
            plt.scatter(k[1], dict[k[0], k[1]][i])
```

and the result looked like this:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204576/filtering-on-the-positive-values-in-scatterplot/76207446#comment134395309_76207446) the OP asked for an alternative capable of plotting distinct colors even if the number of distinct elements in the inner dictionaries exceeds 10. In reply, I suggested the use of a colorbar

[image]

and here it is the code that produced the image above — of course I have changed `dictt` to `dt` to have more elements in the inner dictionaries

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm

from datetime import datetime ### it's better to convert the date strings to date objects
convert = lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

# modified to have a variety of "n"
dt = {('2005-01-04','2006-01-04'):{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:8,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0,10:0}, 
      ('2005-02-03','2006-02-03'):{0:4,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:8,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0,10:4},
      ('2005-03-07','2006-03-07'):{0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0,10:0},
      ('2005-04-06','2006-04-05'):{0:6,1:0,2:0,3:4,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:8,8:8,9:0,10:0}}

nmin, nmax = 0, 10

dates = [convert(d1) for d0, d1 in dt.keys()]

by_n = {}
for (d0, d1), d in dt.items():
        for n in d.keys():
            if n not in by_n: by_n[n] = [] # empty list
            by_n[n].append((convert(d1), d[n] if d[n]>0 else None))

# the scatterplot(s)
cm = plt.get_cmap('cool')
fig, ax0  = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3), layout='constrained')
for day in dates: ax0.scatter(day, 0, s=0)
for n, by_date in by_n.items():
    ax0.scatter(*zip(*by_date), label='n=%d'%n, color=[cm((n-nmin)/(nmax-nmin))], s=80, ec='k')
ax0.set_xticks(dates)

# the colorbar
bounds = [n+0.5 for n in range(nmin-1, nmax+1)]
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, 256)
cb = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm, cm), format='%02d', ax=plt.gca())
# fix the ticks, removing the secondary ones
cb.set_ticks(range(nmin, nmax+1))
cb.set_ticks([], minor=True)
# this is optional, to draw the dividers between colors
for b in bounds:cb.ax.axhline(b, color='k', lw=0.50)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect! Loved what you did with the dates as well.

Comment: @statwoman Your appreciation is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not consistent with your description.

1. If you want to clear the dots on dates '2006-02-03' and '2006-04-05', but keep all dots on other dates:

```py
x = 0   # Set xticks explicitly to keep the date order.
for k in list(dictt.keys()):
    if any(map(lambda x: x > 0, dictt[k[0], k[1]].values())):
        plt.scatter([x]*4, dictt[k[0], k[1]].values())
    x += 1
plt.xticks(range(4), [i[1] for i in dictt.keys()])
```

2. If you want to clear all the non-positive points while keeping the date tick labels:

```py
x = 0
for k in list(dictt.keys()):
    for i in range(4):
        y = dictt[k[0], k[1]][i]
        if y > 0:
            plt.scatter(x, y)
    x += 1
plt.xticks(range(4), [i[1] for i in dictt.keys()])
# You can also set the yticks if you like.
```